# Countdown once event is triggered

Tags: arduino

I'm just getting started with my Arduino and I want to operate a relay for a certain amount of time once I press a contact switch, but still be able to stop the it again at any time by pressing the button again. I've got the press the button to start and stop working Ok, but can't get the timer bit to work at all. Below is what I've got working so far.
TIA.

```
    void setup()
{
  
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(7, INPUT);
  pinMode(6, INPUT);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.print("Pin 7   ");
  Serial.println(digitalRead(7));
  if (digitalRead(6) == LOW && digitalRead(7) == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
    delay(250); // Wait for 250 millisecond(s)
  }
  if (digitalRead(6) == HIGH && digitalRead(7) == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(4, LOW);
    digitalWrite(5, LOW);
    digitalWrite(6, LOW);
    delay(250); // Wait for 250 millisecond(s)
  }
}
```

Comment: I just see delay calls.  I don't see where you're trying to use time at all.  Have a look at the millis function.  It gets timestamps for you that you can use to see how long something has been happening.  There are myriad tutorials on how to use it.  And probably a thousand different questions on this site.

Comment: we usually expect that you spend a reasonable time on finding your own solution via websearch befor you ask volunteers for help. it's a value-other-peoples-time-thing. first I'm not sure why you need 2 inputs and 4 outputs if you say you want to control 1 relay with 1 button. you should read something about non-blocking code, debouncing and probably follow a few more tutorials befor you start to do your own stuff.

Comment: I said relay, but really it will be 3 relays and a LED that I'm controlling. The two delays are for de-bouncing the switch, I found the circuit very touchy without it. I had tried a couple of different things with the millis () function, but it didn't work or didn't work the way I expected. So I got rid of what I tried. I really appreciate the help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool buttonState = 0, buttonStateBefore = 0;
bool toggle = 0;
unsigned long timeNow = 0;
buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
if(buttonState > buttonStateBefore) {
    toggle = !toogle; // negates the toogle
    timeNow = millis(); // milliseconds to the time you press the button
}
buttonStateBefore = buttonState;
if(toggle && millis() < timeNow + delayTime) {
    // relay on
}
else {
    // relay off
}
```

Explanation:
When you press the button, buttonState beign now one, is bigger than the buttonStateBefore. So the if-statement is true. The variable toggle is now true and the time is set to the amount of milliseconds after starting the arduino. After the first if the buttonStateBefore is set to be the buttonState, to not toggle the toggle variable every circle. The second if-statement checks if the toggle variable is true and if the time has not exceeded. If one of the two things is not the case, the relay is turned off.

I hope this is helpful.

P.s. You can shorten your code if you use a for-loop for the digitalWrite

```
for(int i = 3; i < 7; i++) {
    digitalWrite(i, true);
}
```